# Definition of reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Here is a definition: A normed space $X$ is reflexive if $X^{**}=\{\hat{x}:x\in X\}$, where $\hat{x}$ is defined by $\hat{x}(x^*)=x^*(x)$. 
But we know there is a isometric isomorphism between X and $\hat{X}$. Can we directly write A normed space X is reflexive if $X^{**}=X$? And in Conway's book there is a theorem page 132 4.2 Theorem (a)-->(c) 
http://users.math.uoc.gr/~nikosf/FunctionalGrad2015/Conway.pdf
using $X^{**}=X$. How to explain this?
Thank you!

Comment: @klirk Caution: $X^{**}$ might be isomorphic to $X$ but the isomorphism might not be the map $x \mapsto \hat{x}$.  That would not be reflexive.

Comment: Oh, thats right. I forgot about that. I will delte my comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is quite common. However keep in mind that it is a slight abuse of notation because $X$ is only isometrically isomorphic (not equal) to its image  $\hat{X}$.

Comment: But to be more strict we can only get $\hat{X}=X^{**}$ right?

Comment: @AnswerLee Exactly, if you mean more strict in language and not meaning. When people abuse notation to write $X=X^{**}$, they mean precisely that $\hat{X}=X^{**}$.

Comment: So can you explain users.math.uoc.gr/~nikosf/FunctionalGrad2015/Conway.pdf page 132 4.2 Theorem (a)-->(c) to me thank you so much!

Comment: @AnswerLee That's an of the abuse of notation we have been discussing. Conway writes $X=X^{**}$ when he technically means $\hat{X}=X^{**}$. It's very common to see it like that, and I don't think its bad at all. It's just important to be aware of it.

Comment: but if we are to be more strict we can only get $\hat{X}=X^{**}$ then how to get (c) from (a) thank you!

Comment: @AnswerLee It wouldn't change anything. Written in different notation, (c) becomes $\sigma(X^*,\hat{X})=\sigma(X^*,X^{**})$, which follows from $\hat{X}=X^{**}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me but I am sorry I am sure whether we can do that. If we do that, how to get (c) to (b)? And $\sigma(X^*,X)$ means weak topology on $X$ what is $\sigma(X^*,\hat{X})$ meaning?

Comment: @AnswerLee It's just notation. $\sigma(X^*,X)$ is weak* topology on $X^*$ (that is, the weakest topology on $X^*$ making all elements in $\hat{X}$ continuous). You could just as easily call it $\sigma(X^*,\hat{X})$.

Comment: I am sorry I am not getting it. Can you explain more why $\sigma(X^*,X)=\sigma(X^*,\hat{X})$.

Comment: @AnswerLee Because they are two different notations for the same thing. They both mean the weak* topology on $X^*$. If you don't like the abuse of notation $X=X^{**}$, then everywhere you see $\sigma(X^*,X)$, replace it with $\sigma(X^*,\hat{X})$. Or to go further, everywhere you see $X$ used in place of $\hat{X}$, replace it with $\hat{X}$.

Comment: It is helping and I see what you mean. But I don't understand why $\sigma(X^*,\hat{X})$ can stand for the weak topology on $X^*$.

Comment: @AnswerLee No, not the weak topology. It's the weak* topology, which is defined to be the weakest topology on $X^*$ making all elements of $\hat{X}$ continuous. Conway defined it as the weakest topology on $X^*$ making all elements of $X$ continuous, but again he is identifying $X$ with $\hat{X}$ in order to say this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is important to note that this essentially requires the evaluation map $e:X \to X^{**}$ given by $x \mapsto e_x(f):=f(x)$ to be an isomorphism. It is always topologically closed and injective, so you are just asking that $X "=" X^{**}$, but with the condition that this equality can be made explicit by the evaluation map. *Not any old isomorphism will do*.

Comment: But to be more strict we can only get X^=X∗∗X^=X∗∗ right? So can you explain  http://users.math.uoc.gr/~nikosf/FunctionalGrad2015/Conway.pdf  page 132 4.2 Theorem (a)-->(c) to me thank you so much!

Comment: This is not more strict, it is saying that the double dual $X^{**}$ is exactly the image of the evaluation map (that it is surjective) which is enough to guarantee that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: my wifi is currently too slow to open that document--sorry.